# Why aren't my images starting on a new line

Tags: html, css

When I resize the screen my images only respond to a certain extent and then they stop moving. I'm still learning this obviously, so I would appreciate any help in understanding how this all works. My next step will be to reposition the nav from the side to the top on a mobile screen, but I think I understand how to do that.

https://jsfiddle.net/161020/nwkfy6dq/3/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>2006 Inductees</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fahof.css">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/Favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/Favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/Favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="images/Favicon/site.webmanifest">
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">Florence Athletic Hall of Fame</a>
  </div>

  <div id="sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="inductees.html">Inductees&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="information.html">Information&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="citations.html">Citations&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006/bennett_grant.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Bennett_Grant_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 87D5'" alt="Coach Grant Bennett" />
    </a>

    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/bennett_grant.html">Coach<br>Grant 
    Bennett</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Brunson_Lukie_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Lukie Brunson">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/brunson_lukie.html">Lukie Brunson</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Carson_Harry_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid 
     #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Harry Carson">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/carson_harry.html">Harry Carson</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Correll_Vic_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Vic Correll">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/correll_vic.html">Vic Correll</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Hood_Don_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Don Hood">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/hood_don.html">Don Hood</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Jordan_Bobby_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Bobby Jordan">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/jordan_bobby.html">Bobby Jordan</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Law_Jolette_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Jolette Law">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/law_jolette.html">Jollette Law</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Moore_Pearl_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Pearl Moore">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/moore_pearl.html">Pearl Moore</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Wall_Jim_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Jim Wall">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/wall_jim.html">Jim Wall</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="2006_inductees.html">
      <img src="2006/_images/Walters_Joey_small.JPG" height="136px" style="border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5" onmouseover="style='border:3px solid #000000'" onmouseout="style='border:3px solid 
    #2F87D5'" alt="Joey Walters">
    </a>
    <div class="name" style="text-align: center;"><a href="2006/walters_joey.html">Joey Walters</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>Chick-Fil-A Florence Athletic Hall of Fame<br> P.O. Box 1476<br> Florence SC 29503
  </footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some more information to your question?
It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to make the site more responsive. When the screen is minimized I want the images to change from two rows to however many is necessary to fit them all on the screen. Currently it keeps them on two rows and requires side scrolling to see them all

Comment: dear just engrave this into your knowledge set when it comes to word responsive CSS media queries are way to go. they adjust to various screen sizes right it seems as though things are being adjust by the browsers liking. thats my hinch is whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve responsiveness using the flexbox layout. Looking at you codebase, you need to put all your gallery images inside a div which will serve as a container. Something like the below.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="2006/bennett_grant.html"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery">
        <a href="2006_inductees.html">
...........
</div> <!-- end of flex container -->
```

Then in your CSS

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

make sure you set a width for the gallery class.

Now your pictures will be responsive.

Comment: @dc0465816 if you accepted the answer, you should vote up the answer.